# Central Equation and the Formal Proof of Bloch's Theorem by Kittel

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, solid-state-physics, crystals

I am a bit confused over Kittel's derivation of Bloch's theorem:
[image]
[image]
[image]

My question lies in eq. 29. The k+G is only a subset of possible k value that satisfy the periodic boundary condition. Why is it proper to determine that there does not exist a $k'$ such that $k'\neq k+G$ and the corresponding coefficient for the series $C_{k'}$ would be non-zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting correctly, this is the troublesome sentence:

> If one particular wavevector $k$ is contained in a $\psi$,
> then all other wavevectors in the Fourier expansion of this $\psi$ will have the
> form $k+G$, where $G$ is any reciprocal lattice vector.

Now, you ask why. The answer is that, well, Charles Kittel is lying here. They're not looking for just any solutions, they're looking for a helpful set of solutions. Let's take a step back and derive the central equation
$$
(\lambda_k - \epsilon)C(k) + \sum_{G}U_GC(k-G) = 0.
$$

Starting at the previous equation:
$$
\sum_k \lambda_k C(k) e^{ikx} + \sum_G\sum_k U_GC(k)e^{i(k+G)x} = \epsilon\sum_kC(k)e^{ikx}
$$
The second term on the right side can be rearranged:
$$
\sum_G\sum_k U_GC(k)e^{i(k+G)x} = \sum_k\left(\sum_GU_gC(k-G)\right)e^{ikx}
$$
and then we get to rearrange the previous equation to have a sum over $k$ on one side, zero on the other:
$$
\sum_k \left((\lambda_k - \epsilon) C(k) + \sum_GU_gC(k-G)\right)e^{ikx} = 0
$$
Only way for this to be true is for the coefficients to each be zero:
$$
(\lambda_k - \epsilon) C(k) + \sum_GU_gC(k-G) = 0
$$
Once we have a $k_0$ value with $C(k_0)\neq 0$, we have all of the $C(k_0-G)$ coefficients determined by the central equation. Moreover, saying that $C(k\neq k_0-G) = 0$ will yield a valid wavefunction with energy $\epsilon$.

But what if $C(k\neq k_0-G)\neq 0$? Well, the honest answer is that we end up with the same result: a wavefunction with energy $\epsilon$. There's nothing actually stopping us from having a wavefunction which includes *all* wavevectors $k$ with the right energy $\epsilon$.

But the helpful part of using $C(k\neq k_0-G) = 0$ is that it organizes the solutions into a set of $\psi_k$ with wonderful properties:

1. The solutions $\psi_k$ form a *basis*.
2. The solutions $\psi_k$ are *mutually orthogonal*.

Property 1 means that if $\psi$ satisfies the equation $\mathcal H\psi =  \epsilon\psi$ then $\psi$ can be expressed as a combination (or superposition) of $\psi_k$s:
$$
\psi(x) = \sum_k A_k\psi_k(x).
$$
And property 2 means that if $k'\neq k+G$ then their *inner product* is zero:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi_k(x)^* \psi_{k'}(x)\,\mathrm dx = 0.
$$

The second property has some implications in quantum mechanics. In principle, we could measure the wavevector of any wavefunction $\psi$. If $\psi$ is one of our special solutions, $\psi_k$, then measuring the wavevector is *guaranteed* to yield $k$. The same cannot be said for an arbitrary $\psi$. For example, if we have wavevectors $k_1$ through $k_4$, then we can construct a wavefunction $\psi$:
$$
\psi(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\psi_{k_1}(x) + \psi_{k_2}(x) + \psi_{k_3}(x) + \psi_{k_4}(x)\right)
$$
If we try to measure the wavevector of $\psi$, there is a $1/4$ chance of measuring each $k_1$ through $k_4$.

Comment: "The answer is that, well, Charles Kittel is lying here." No, he is not. IIRC, earlier in the book he derives Bloch theorem using translation operator, and thereby already knows that the wavefunction should look like $\psi_k=e^{ikr}u(r)$ where $u(r)$ has lattice symmetry. So he is totally justified to only seek the wavefunctions that have this form.

Comment: "There's nothing actually stopping us from having _all_ values of $k$ represented." Actually, just because you need a constant eigen-energy $\epsilon$, it is clear that there will only be a handful of $k$ points inside the 1BZ that would have the exact same eigen-energy. You can thus only pick from those points.

Comment: Of course, I think you already know these. Just felt that a good answer deserves to be made perfect.

Comment: That's totally correct that not all $k$ values have the right energy. I'll edit the answer today

Comment: On the other hand, while Kittel is justified in looking for wavefunctions of this form, the statement I quoted is not true. The earlier proof was *in the absence of degeneracy*. In this proof, the statement that "if $k$ is in $\psi$ then all other wavevectors in the Fourier expansion will be of the form $k+G$" is not correct. You *can* have a wavevector with a well-defined energy which has $k$ and $k'\neq k+G$ in its Fourier expansion (like the $\psi$ I constructed at the end).

Comment: I see. Does it mean that solutions to in which there are coefficients $C(k'\neq k_0-G)\neq0$ can actually exist, and just imply superposition of different degenerate states?

Comment: @蕭力諶 yes, that's correct

Comment: And while the solution is a superposition of different of Bloch state basis functions, it is still a Bloch state, right?

Comment: @蕭力諶 No, it will not be, and that is the point. If you want to be a Bloch state, in particular, if you want to be a simultaneous eigenfunction of Hamiltonian and Translation operators, then you need to only have one single $k$ in the 1BZ and no more. The concept that is appearing here is the same as that in single atoms: The different $m_j$ in H atom for the same $n,\ell,s,j$ have the same energy, but if you superpose them, they will no longer be $J_z$ eigenstates. Nobody is saying that every solution of TISE is in $J_z$ eigenstates, but rather that they span the whole Hilbert space.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I see. Is it proper to say that a solution is not necessarily a Bloch state and an eigenstate of Hamiltonian is not necessarily an eigenstate of translation operators, and Bloch's theorem is merely stating the existence of a complete basis taking the form of Bloch states?

Comment: @蕭力諶 Yes, and that is always the case, not just in the Bloch–translation case. We are almost always interested in some maximally commuting set of operators that include the Hamiltonian, and if you swap some of them for others, the old complete basis will span the same space as the new basis but will appear as superpositions that will violate the eigenvalue equation for the operators that are swapped out.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Thank you very much. I finally get it.

Comment: Also great thanks to @JacobStuligross